# Connecting to cassandra running in Docker

Tags: docker, cassandra

I'm trying to run Cassandra in a docker container and connect to it from my Mac (the host) but I keep getting Connection refused errors.

The docker command:

```
=> docker run --rm --name cassandra -d cassandra:3.11 -p 9042:9042

=> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                    NAMES
4ecc9dcd8647        cassandra:3.11      "/docker-entrypoin..."   33 minutes ago      Up 33 minutes       7000-7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9042/tcp, 9160/tcp   cassandra

=> cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': 
error(61, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: 
Connection refused")})
```

If I'm executing bash shell in the instance:

```
=> docker exec -it cassandra bash
```

I can run the cqlsh and connect to cassandra locally.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Port is still not exposed outside
Try this

- docker run -p 9042:9042 --rm --name cassandra -d cassandra:3.11

Do docker ps you should see something like this

- 0.0.0.0:9042->9042/tcp

For more info : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Comment: Thank you!
I'm surprised that the options order matters. Do you know if it is documented somewhere?

Comment: I just wanted to thank you because I've been going mental trying to connect to my Cassandra container using TablePlus and have been going 'round circles. It doesn't by default open port 9042 when following the instructions shown on their website: https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html

Answer (score 8):

Anything passed after docker image name  it considers argument to the container entrypoint.

```
cassandra:3.11 -p 9042:9042
```

so actually docker pass `-p 9042:9042` this as an argument to the entrypoint, you can very this by inspecting docker container.

To run and publish port

```
docker run -it  - - name cassandra -e CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=cassandra --rm docker.io/bitnami/cassandra:3-debian-10
```

Once container up then verify connection

```
docker exec -it cassandra bash -c "cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra"
```